# Reactjs - Splitting table row into two rows - fields are not aligning properly

Tags: reactjs, html-table

Am trying to split table row into two rows. So, i writting two tr tag in my render() method. Am able to split the rows but, its alignment is not coming properly.

All the fields are rendering in the first column itself. How can i split the table properly.

Am using Reactjs V 15.6.1

```
class Details extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);   
    this.state = { item: props.item };
    }

            render() {

            return (
            <table className="table table-bordered" style={{fontsize: '8'}}>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Line Number</th>
                        <th>Product Code</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Unit Price</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <DetailsList items={ this.state.item.order_items }  />
            </table>
        );   
    }
}

class DetailsList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { };
    }
 render() {
       return (<tbody>{ this.props.items.map((item) => <DetailsItem key={ 
 item.line_id } item={ item } />) }
                  </tbody>);    
        }
}

class DetailsItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { item: props.item };
    }


    render() {
        return (<tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input name="line_number" type="text"  
                     value={ this.state.item.line_number }  /> </td>
                <td><input name="product_code" type="text"
                     value={ this.state.item.product_code }  /></td>
                <td><input name="product_description" type="text"
                     value={ this.state.item.product_description } /> </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{ this.state.item.product_quantity } </td>
                <td>{ this.state.item.unit_net_price } </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        );
    }
}
```

Please find my output screenshot below. All fields are rendered in the same column. Its happening while am adding second table row tag.

[image]
Also, if remove `<tbody>` tag from the `return()` method also its throwing error `Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag`.

Comment: There's not enough information here to help. How is DetailsItem and DetailsList called? Show the resulting html or give a minimal reproduction. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: DetailsList has been called from Details and DetailsItem has been called from DetailsList. Code has been updated with more information.

Comment: Please find the attached screenshot that am getting as a result out of the code. All the fields are assigned to the same column.

Comment: @dgrogan - I have updated my code along with my output screenshot.

Comment: Unless I'm blind, you're not setting state in your `Details` component. You render `<DetailsList items={ this.state.item.order_items }  />` but in your constructor you never initialize state.

Comment: I set the state variable    `this.state = { item: props.item };`    in Details Component. In DetailsList component i mapped with the props variable itself. So that am not initialize state in constructor.     `return (<tbody>{ this.props.items.map((item) => <DetailsItem key={ 
 item.line_id } item={ item } />) }`

Comment: @KyleRichardson  In `DetailsItem` component's constructor am initializing the state `this.state = { item: props.item };` . Code is working properly but the actual issue occurs only when am trying to split the table row.  `<tr>` tag.

Comment: @Karthikeyan you need to remove the second `tr` from the `DetailsItem` and add the contents of it to the first `tr`.

Comment: @HamzaBaig No, that is my requirement. I dont have much space to show in first `<tr>` tag itself. Thats why i want to bring it to second `<tr>`

Comment: @Karthikeyan then its not gonna work. <td> tags should match the number of <th> tags otherwise alignment's gonna mess up. What you need i think is, in the last <td> add a <div> inside and the remaining 2 <td> and style the div with css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReactJS V 15.x.x only allow one components within render() method. Its not possible to return multiple `<tr>` tag. This has been addressed from ReactJS 16+ `https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html`.